# Writing forms of an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

> Let $x>1/2$. What is the simplest form of the expression $(1+\sqrt{2x-1})/(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{2x-1}})$

Let $a=\sqrt{2x-1}$

$(1+a)/(\sqrt{x+a})$

=$(1+a)/(x+a)^{1/2}$

=$(1+a)(\sqrt{x+a})$

=$\sqrt{x+a}*a*\sqrt{x+a}$

=$(x+a)(a)$

=$xa+a^2$

=$(x+a)*a$

Plug in $a=\sqrt{2x-1}$

=$(x+\sqrt{2x-1})(\sqrt{2x-1})$

=$x\sqrt{2x-1}+2x-1$

Now plug in $x>1/2$

=$1/2\sqrt{2(1/2)-1}+2(1/2)-1$=$0$

I was trying to solve this problem and was not sure if I was doing it right. I am still not sure on what to do. Can someone please help me with this solution?

**I just found out there was an error to the problem posted earlier in the book I was reading from. This is suppose to be the real one.**

Comment: What do you mean "plug in $x\gt 1/2$"? You mean $x=1/2$? Also, the denominator is $\sqrt{x+\sqrt{2x-1}}$ ?

Comment: I was trying to solve this problem and got a little confused on some things. It became exhausting for me. Can you help me fix it up?

Comment: @mathlove Yes that is what I wanted the denominator to be. I supposed that since $x>1/2$ that we could plug in $1/2$.

Comment: According to your work, the numerator's square root has a *minus* inside instead of a *plus*. Which is it? (The answer's particularly-nice if there really is a *minus*.)

Comment: @Blue The problem as posted now is the way I wanted it.

Answer (score 2):

If you multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{2x-1}}$ the denominator becomes 
$$
\sqrt{x^2 - (2x - 1)} = \sqrt{(x-1)^2} = x-1
$$

now you've just got to figure out the numerator
$$
\left( \sqrt{x-\sqrt{2x-1}} \right)  \left( 1+\sqrt{2x+1} \right)
$$

**Edit:**
Now that you've fixed the numerator to $(1+\sqrt{2x-1})$ that makes things quite a bit simpler. The other solution is nicer with that fix, though I did figure out that you can get the same answer from here as well.
$$
\left( \sqrt{x-\sqrt{2x-1}} \right)  \left( 1+\sqrt{2x-1} \right)
= \sqrt{(x-\sqrt{2x-1})(1+\sqrt{2x-1})^2}
$$
Which ends up simplifying to something similar to above
$$
\sqrt{2(x-\sqrt{2x-1})(x+\sqrt{2x-1})} = \sqrt{2(x-1)^2} 
$$
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}(x-1)}{(x-1)} = \sqrt{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\text{numerator}^2 = \left(\; 1 + \sqrt{2x-1} \;\right)^2 &= 1^2 \;+\; \sqrt{2x-1}^2 \;+\; 2\cdot 1 \cdot \sqrt{2x-1} \\[4pt]
&= 1 + (2x-1) + 2\sqrt{2x-1} \\[4pt]
&= 2\;\left(\;x + \sqrt{2x-1}\;\right) \\[4pt]
&= 2 \; \text{denominator}^2
\end{align}$$
Since the numerator and denominator are necessarily positive, we can take square roots without sign ambiguity, and then write 
$$\frac{\text{numerator}}{\text{denominator}} = \frac{\sqrt{2} \;\; \text{denominator}}{\text{denominator}} = \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for helping. I was not too sure about the numerator after working it out for a few things. It is nice how that works out for $x>1/2.$ Thank you!